# MRU change request failed, device already open

Tags: quectel

I am using the Quectal AG550Q and AG215s modules and when connecting to minicom,it is showing this error.Can you please suggest any ways to remove this error.

rmnet_usb 2-1:1.2: MRU change request to 0x4000

[ 669.208305] rmnet_usb 2-1:1.2: MRU change request failed, device already open

[ 669.212864] rmnet_usb 2-1:1.2 rmnet_usb1: usbnet_open

We were expecting not to see this error.